# How to extend 1U / 2U servers with multiple 2 slot full height GPUs for sharing?

Tags: pci-express, gpu, external-connection

What are the possible options to extend a 1U / 2U server with a GPU?

e.g. I am searching for a solution how to add a GTX 1650 into the server. The GPU is usually 2 slots width and therefore often not fitting into a 1U/2U server

for what usage?

- i want to do a directIO passthrough to a virtualized OS to have a "native" access to a GPU. E.g. for video or GPU intensive renderings (blender, Davinci and so on)

Already tried the x1 adapters to simulate a external x16 slot, which are typically used for mining, but the performance was a big issue

are there any standards to switch to?

any suggestions for a solution for shared GPUs?

Comment: Get a case into which the GPU fits.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it

Comment: or buy a special graphic card that can be shared, remind its expensive (nvidia has some kind of this)

Comment: @dijdomi i am not requesting a product or service. This is a question afaik, which i simply trying to solve a question in a rack environment. Right now a search did not report me any reasonable answer, therefore asking here the community for a common standard

Comment: Give the server vendor a call?

Answer (score 1):

Many 1U and 2U cases servers mount full-size PCIe cards horizontally using a PCIe riser card. Find a server with a case that has enough room for your card.

This is a feature that you must choose when you select a server.

[image]

For example this 1U server (which might be be a SYS110P-WTR) can mount two full-size PCIe cards (or one double width card) and one low-profile card (on the back of the riser)

Servers with preinstalled GPUs are also available.